# sql keyword IN using RSQLite and DBI package

Tags: sql, r, r-dbi, rsqlite

When using the RSQLite and DBI package to form a query, I wonder if there is a way to use SQL keyword IN?

I don't think SQL keyword IN is currently implemented?

e.g.

```
## instead of:
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl = :targetCyl" , 
params = list( targetCyl = 4 ))

## I want to do the following:

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl IN :targetCyl" , 
params = list( targetCyl = c( 2, 4, 6 ) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SQL's `IN` operator requires its arguments to be in parentheses, as in

   ```sql
   select * from mtcars where cyl in (?,?,?)
   ```
2. `DBI` requires you to instantiate the number of parens you need, as in

   ```r
   targetCyl <- c( 2, 4, 6 )
   dbGetQuery(
     con, paste("SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl IN (",
                paste(rep("?", length(targetCyl)), collapse = ","), ")"),
     params = as.list(targetCyl))
   ```

FYI, this is not specific to SQLite or `RSQLite`, it's `DBI` in general.